# Simply Convert Razor Dropdown List to Bootstrap3 Dropdown List with specified actions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is the Dropdown List created in Razor View:

```
var currencies = Model.AvailableCurrencies.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {

        Text = x.Name,
        Value = webHelper.ModifyQueryString(Url.RouteUrl("ChangeCurrency", new { customercurrency = x.Id }), "returnurl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl), null),
        Selected = x.Id.Equals(Model.CurrentCurrencyId)                                  
    });


        @Html.DropDownList("customerCurrency", currencies, new { onchange = "setLocation(this.value);"  })
```

I Need to make a Bootstrap-3 Dropdown List Like:

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" href="#">Currency&nbsp;
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" >
    @foreach(var currency in Model.AvailableCurrencies)
    {
         <li><a href="">@currency.Name</a></li>
    }     
</ul>
```

But how to define the action of those list items as it is done on previous code on razor?
Please help with some code...

Comment: why dont you make your own HtmlHelper that will generate what HTML you want?

Comment: I don't want to write any javascript or helper in this case. Is there any way i can write the actions defined in bootstrap html elements as defined on previous razor view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i did not want to use any javascript that is the perfect answer-

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" href="#">
    @foreach(var just_currency in currencies)
    {
        if(just_currency.Selected==true)
        {
            @just_currency.Text
        }
    }
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" >

    @foreach(var currency in currencies)
    {
        <li><a href="@currency.Value" >@currency.Text</a></li>

    }     

</ul>
```

`@Dropdownlist` creates HTML dropdownlist as `select option`. But i was trying to create `ul li` on bootstrap and in the mean time the selected option must to be shown as selected item. So I created that code. I think everyone will like this. Thanks everybody for trying.

Comment: does this mark the item in the list as active though? It looks like it just sets the text of the button and there is no active item in the list when the dropdown is opened.

Answer (score 1):

You could write extension methods to do so:

```
namespace Your.Namespace.Goes.Here {
    public static class HtmlExtensions {
        public static string BootstrapDropdown(this HtmlHelper helper, /* params go here */) {
            // list generation code goes here
        }
    }
}
```

You must then register the extension methods to the Razor Engine in your `Views/Web.config`

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />

            <add namespace="Your.Namespace.Goes.Here" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assign an id to your hyperlinks as an attribute like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" >
    @foreach(var currency in Model.AvailableCurrencies)
    {
         <li><a href="" id="@currency.Id">@currency.Name</a></li>
    }     
</ul>
```

Then attach a click event to all the hyperlinks and read the id back out:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
      event.preventDefault();
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      setLocation(id)

   });
```

Please see this jsFiddle for a full working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/srz7A/1/

Please note that the setLocation only writes the id out to the console in the above demo.